# How to pass file content as a command argument in Windows cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd, nsis

I want to do something like bash

```
kill -9 `cat pid.txt`
```

in Windows. I tried

```
set /p mypid= < pid.txt && taskkill /f /pid %mypid%
```

but it doesn't work, looks like `%mypid%` becomes assigned after executing of `taskkill`.

How to do it? (I'm going to call this command from NSIS install script, so I don't want to make a separate `.bat` file for it).

Comment: The Windows platform lacks several mechanisms common on the Linux/Unix world. You could try to fragment the process: 1) read the pid file and 2) pass it to `taskkill`

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure what the contents of pid.txt are, but assuming it's just the PID by itself, you could do this:

```
for /f %%x in (pid.txt) do taskkill /f /pid %%x
```

If you're running that from the command line, and not as part of a batch file, replace the `%%x` with `%x`.

If that's not what is in pid.txt, please edit your question to be clearer on that point.

Comment: Thank you. The `pid.txt` is just PID itself. But when I tried to run it, Windows just executed notepad with `pid.txt` for me.

Comment: Outstanding!  I had no idea Windows batch files could do that!  Thanks.

Comment: It only generate an error for me : `%%x was unnexpected`

Comment: If you're running that directly from the command line but NOT in a batch file, use `%x` rather than `%%x`.

Answer (score 1):

The following script is doing what you expect, without depending on a shell feature:

```
OutFile "kill.exe"

Var pid
!define filename "pid.txt"

Section

    ClearErrors
    FileOpen $0 "${filename}" r
    IfErrors 0 readok
    DetailPrint "Error to open ${filename}"
    goto done
    readok:
    FileRead $0 $pid
    DetailPrint "pid found=$pid"
    FileClose $0

    ExecWait 'taskkill /F /PID $pid'
    done:

SectionEnd
```